# MSComCtl2.MonthView license

Tags: .net, com, activex, licensing

We are using MSComCtl2.MonthView in an add-on/snap-in application that plugs into a 3rd party ActiveX host.  The host has limited ActiveX support: it does not seem to support ActiveX licensing, and only supports creating the control instance itself (not allowing the add-on to create the control), so we can't use the normal "Licenses.Add" solution to provide the license from our compiled application.  The only other solution seems to be to deploy the license with our application into Licenses/4F86BADF-9F77-11d1-B1B7-0000F8753F5D in the registry.  But I can't find anything to indicate what the requirements are for that to be legal.  Do they need to own any particular software for that to be legal?  I see that the license is installed on some systems under Wow6432Node, but that's not the right place for the license, so apparently some software that does install the license exists on these systems, but doesn't put it in the right place.  I just can't figure out what that software is, or if we're OK to just install it in the right place with our own installer outright.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's response is that the machine could/should have the free SQL Reporting Services installed (or any of a number of other products) in order to acquire the license for the control.